# Xamarin Cross-Platform e Códigos "Nativos"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Bom dia,

iniciei recentemente um estudo no desenvolvimento multiplataforma, e agora estou avaliando o Xamarin (Visual Studio 2017), porém estou tendo dificuldade em algumas questões. A principal delas é a possibilidade de sobrescrever à classe "comum" com códigos nativos, estou tentando configurar a activity inicial para permanecer PORTRAIT no Android, encontrei o código para isso.

```
[Activity(Label = "App2", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

Porém isso não é aplicado ao meu aplicativo quando o executo, na verdade, nada que eu faça na Activity parece afetar o aplicativo. Existe algum processo que possa estar faltando? É necessário linkar a activity (MainActivity) ao CS "comum"?

**A questão, para resumir, o que é necessário para que a activity (Android) impacte no aplicativo se o mesmo for rodado nesta plataforma?**

Pesquisei horrores e ainda não encontrei nada sobre isso, qualquer luz seria bem vinda, um tutorial, um ponto de partida, qualquer coisa. Mesmo que em inglês.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, o que você procura é o `#if __ANDROID__`??? https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation

Comment: Não, é que na parte do android existe uma MainActivity, e para que eu deixe ela com orientação somente Portrait preciso fazer essa alteração da pergunta, a questão é que mesmo fazendo essa alteração nada acontece, mesmo que eu limpe o código da Activity nada acontece, como se o aplicativo estivesse ignorando essa Activity. O que eu gostaria de saber é se existe algum processo para realizar que faça o app considerar esta Activity, que é a padrão de quando se cria o projeto Xamarin no VS2017

Answer (score 0):

Tente ir no arquivo de manifesto e configure a orientação para quais atividades quiser:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

android:configChanges diz ao Android que você é o responsável pelas mudanças de orientação.
android:screenOrientation="portrait" configura o seu padrão de orientação para retrato.